# JQuery autocomplete retrieving all database value whatever type in textbox

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to search data from database by autocomplete search in database.but whenever i type something in textbox then it display all data which is in database.

here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
        $( "#task" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ 
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>digital/task_search",
                data: { term: $("#task").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
        });
      });
    });
```

here is my textbox in view

```
<input type="text" name="work" class="form-control" id="task" placeholder="Types of Work">
```

Here is my model:

```
public function search_task($term){
        $this->db->select('work_name');
        $this->db->like('work_name', $term, 'after');
        $query = $this->db->get('task_name');
        return $query->result();


    }
```

Here is my controller

```
public function task_search(){
        $term = $this->input->post('work');


        $rows = $this->digital_hodm_model->search_task($term);

        $json_array = array();
        foreach ($rows as $row)
             array_push($json_array, $row->work_name);

        echo json_encode($json_array);


    }
```

Please help me to find out the solution. It already takes my whole days..please help

Comment: Is there anyone available please help me

Comment: please help me to find out the solution. I try lots of thing but didn't get the solution

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with php so please check your server side method that get result and get top records.